# Do I also need to apply thinset to my Subway tiles or is it enough to just put it on the wall?

Tags: tile, bathtub, ceramic-tile, thinset

Subway tile question regarding a bathtub surround.

Do I need to apply thinset on the back of the tile?
Subway tiles are small, can I just put thinset on the wall and apply the tiles?

Thank you

Comment: Follow the manufacturer's instructions for installing their tile. Good luck!

Comment: yeah, there's no instructions booklet of any kind. Just a box of tile.

Comment: Try looking them up on the web....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Back-Buttering shouldn't be needed. But, the best determination is to set a tile & then pry it off. You should have a nice even smush of Thin-set that covers the whole back of the tile. If you don't get full coverage, then you can try it again with a bigger notch trowel...on a fresh clean tile. If that doesn't do it, then you'll want to back-butter every tile.

Answer (score 0):

You can press the tiles into the thinset on the wall and they will stick two much thinset and they will move around. Make sure with small tiles to use a finer notched trowel and with larger the bigger notches. Here is a [fine notch trowel](http://www.homedepot.com/p/HDX-1-8-in-x-1-8-in-x-1-8-in-Square-Notch-Economy-Trowel-10123X/203714528). With vertical tiles I sometimes use mastic because it sets faster than thinset especially with small tiles that are easily knocked out of position. [mastic / tile adhesive](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Custom-Building-Products-AcrylPro-1-Gal-Ceramic-Tile-Adhesive-ARL40001/100015587).